# Text selection / personalisation for different users

Tags: machine-learning, personalization

I have the following scenario:

There are a list of headings:

1. Best Holiday Destination for you
2. Choose us for your next vacation
3. Don't miss out on this offer

What I want to achieve is, display the best heading for the right user through a ML model?

One approach is to show all these headings to different users through maybe an A/B/C test and see the statistics and feed the data into the model and optimise it for a certain goal? e.g click through rate, etc

Is there any other way to do something like this?

Answer (score -1):

Do you want to use your own code, or is it fine for you to use an external tool?

If it's fine, I can suggest twik personalization tool.

If you want to use your own code, you need to start with the A/B/C testing, but you need to collect more info about each user (i.e., age group, location, interests & socioeconomic status), not only the text click-through rate. This way, your code will be able to know better to which audience presents each variant.